# uml - Class diagram of node-edge relation

Tags: uml, graph-theory, class-diagram, directed-graph

I'm trying to create a class diagram for a node-edge relationship, as it would be found in a directed graph. I want to convey that `Nodes` have references to `Edges`, and `Edges` also have references to `Nodes`.
Every `Edge` needs exactly two `Nodes` (source and target).

Would this be an acceptable way to model this?

[image: class diagram node-edge]

Comment: Just looks fine to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this diagram expresses perfectly what you describe in the text.  The doubled association is right: each association expresses something different.

You are somewhat more precise in the diagram than in the text, since you show that each node has `inEdges` and `outEdges`, whereas the text just mentions the reference to `Edges` without being more explicit.

A common variant for the implementation of directed graph is that the `Node` knows only its `outEdges`. If this is important, you may express it with [navigability](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#navigability), with an arrow in direction of `sourceNode` and a cross on the side of `inEdges`.  But this practice is relatively rare in the model.

For an undirected graph, you could have only one association with a multiplicity of 2 on the side of the nodes.

Comment: Yes, both incoming and outcoming edges are known by the node. Thank you!